# How could I use a class component inside function component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

We can use function component inside a class component, is it possible to do the other way around? For example

```
class MyClassComponent extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>This is a class component with display {this.props.display}</p>
        )
    }
}
const MyFunctionComponent = (props) => {
    return <MyClassComponent display=props.shouldDisplay>This is a function component</MyClassComponent >
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

React makes it transparent for you whether the components you use are functions or classes, so you can compose them as you like.

Specifically in your code there are two issues that you might want to reconsider:

1. When you define a prop, its value should be wrapped in curly brackets:

```
<MyClassComponent display={props.shouldDisplay}>
```

2. Components can be either self-closing or have children props. In your case, you've added text inside the opening tag and the closing tag, which you can access in `MyClassComponent` via `this.props.children`:

```
const ChildComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            {this.props.children}
        </div>
    );
}

const ParentComponent = (props) => {
    return (
        <ChildComponent>
            Hello World
        </ChildComponent>
    );
}

const App = (props) => {
    return <ParentComponent/>;
}
```